# cURLpp installation

Tags: c++, installation, curlpp

I have downloaded, compiled and installed cURLpp.
When I try to compile the example, it says that the headers can't be found (curlpp/curlpp.hpp etc.) but they are present in /usr/local/include. How do I add the library to my project?

I am using Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: What is the command line used to compile the example? and the #includes in the example?

Comment: I am trying to compile this: http://curlpp.org/index.php/examples/47-example-00

Comment: Currently I can't look it up because I'm not at my home pc, sorry... but I use Code::Blocks and haven't changed anything in its configuration but I added the library (.so) files to my project.